# Different documents considered as duplicates in search results

Tags: 2010, search-results, duplicate

In our Customer Center publication site (SP 2010), we have uploaded two different documents that have big parts of text in common. They are similar, but not equal. Although different documents, in the search results they are returned as duplicates: only one of both documents is shown whereas the other can only be accessed by clicking on 'View Duplicates'.

After reading on some Internet, I found out that these documents are considered as duplicates due to the fact that they are considered as 'near-duplicates'.

Apparently, when documents have a certain amount of chunks of matching text or content, these matches are enough for SharePoint to consider the documents as duplicates, even if the file name or metadata of both documents are different!

This is the URL of the site where I found this information: http://www.aquaforest.com/wp/index.php/finding-duplicate-files-in-sharepoint/

Does anyone know of a method or some kind of workaround to avoid these 'false' duplicates in the search results?

Comment: I have run into the same issue a few times. All you can do is configure the search result to not remove duplicates. I have done this several times and not run in to any problems with actual duplicates being shown.

Comment: You sure the documents are no renamed copies?

Comment: Thanks all for your swift replies, Steven and Ransher, I am afraid I do not have the proper rights to change the search result settings. I can only change some 'Search and offline available' settings in the Site Administration settings. Wout, good question, but no, the documents have differing content, although they have considerable amounts of text that is completely identical. Best regards,
Stijn

Answer (score -1):

As Steven suggested, you need to turn **off "Trim duplicates"** option.

1. First export the current Search Results WebPart.
2. Open the WebPart in Notepad.
3. Search for the TrimDuplicates attribute and set it to "**false**"
4. Save and import the WebPart.
5. Replace the current results WebPart on your results page with the imported one.

Comment: There's no need to export, edit and re-import the web part, it can be done in the web part settings.